# BASH script errors using `while` and a numeric relational test

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to create BASH file to create 50 users with while.
But i got some problems when i run it.

```
limite=51
num=1

while [$numero != $limite]
do
  echo -n 'enter your name: ' "$num" ; read name
  sudo useradd $name
  num=$(($num + 1))
done
```

the problems come from line 1 and line 4

I don't know why!?

WEll, i have  this and it works

```
limite=51
num=1

while [ $num != $limite ] ; do
  echo -n 'enter your name: ' "$num" ; read name
  sudo useradd $name
  num=$(($num + 1))   
done
```

Thx to you

Comment: What "problems" do you get? p.s `$numero` is not defined anywhere. Shouldn't it be `num` ?

Comment: sorry num = numero i rename it but he doesn't do the while

Comment: The problem is likely `[1: command not found`.

Comment: Glad you got it working, don't forget to tick the answer that helped you sort it.

Comment: post you error messages please

Comment: Or maybe `[1: bad pattern`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[` is actually a command so it needs a space after it, line 4 should be

```
while [ $numero != $limite ]

# See it's actually a command
$ which [        
/usr/bin/[
```

Just like `catfile1` would complain so does `[$numero`, do `man test` for more information or even `man bash`.

Also if this is the complete script what is `$numero`, should it be `$num`?

Comment: thx it works now. $num = $numero i have to rename it.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash idiom, your script would be better written as

```
limite=51

for ((num=1;num<limite;++num)); do
    read -p "enter your name: $num" name
    sudo useradd "$name"
done
```

Or better yet (it will be quicker): enter all the usernames in a file, say `user.txt`, one name per line, and run

```
while read name; do sudo useradd "$name"; done < user.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell is pretty pedantic about where it wants whitespace (to perform what is called **word splitting**):

```
while [ $numero != $limite ]; do
  echo ...
done
```

should do the trick. And you should decide whether you want to use `$numero` or `$num`... as posted it won't work because `$numero` is used uninitialized.

Some background: the grammar for a `while` compound statement is

```
while list; do list; done
```

A list can be a program like `[` (who said programs can't have funny names like `/usr/bin/[`?) So the `while` actually calls the `[` program with 4 arguments: the expansion of `$numero`, `!=`, the expansion of `$limits` and `]` (which is a useless argument, but makes the syntax look pretty.)

The `[` program is the same as the `test` program; the latter not requiring the useless `]` argument. In fact, I prefer to write all my conditionals using `test`:

```
while test $numero != $limite; do
  echo ...
done
```

Another hint: the semicolon `;` is a *statement separator* and does not require white space in front of it.

Comment: Is `$numero` a magic variable generated somehow? (I don't know bash but the script looks wrong).

Comment: my first bash and its a little hard haha